# rbind based on columns name and exclude no match

Tags: r

Sample data:

```
l <- list(x=data.frame(X1=1,X2=2,X3=3,X4=4,X5=5),
          y=data.frame(X1=6,X8=7,X4=8,X9=9,X5=10),
          z=data.frame(X1=11,X2=12,X3=13,X4=14,X5=15)
          )
```

I would like to `rbind` this list based on pre-specified column names, so that the column name (and it's column position matches).

```
# these are pre-defined columns names we want to `rbind` if no match, exclude the list entry
col <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")
```

The desired output should be `data.frame`:

```
  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
   1   2   3   4   5
  11  12  13  14  15
```

EDIT: maybe like this:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) x[!any(is.na(match(c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"), names(x))))]))
```

Comment: Can there be an entry with the column names `c(col, somethingElse)`? i.e. an entry with redundant columns.

Comment: @ Julius, no it can't be. Not matching list must be excluded entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
match_all_columns <- function (d, col) {
  if (all(names(d) %in% col)) {
    out <- d[, col]
  } else {
    out <- NULL
  }
  out
}
# or as a one-liner
match_all_columns <- function (d, col) if (all(names(d) %in% col)) d[col]

matched_data <- lapply(l, match_all_columns, col)
result <- do.call(rbind, matched_data)
result
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# x  1  2  3  4  5
# z 11 12 13 14 15
```

`rbind` knows to just ignore the `NULL` elements.

edit: I swapped `d[, col]` with `d[col]` because a) it looks nicer, b) it prevents the data frame being dropped to a vector if `col` only has one element, and c) I think it's slightly more performant on large data frames.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another possibility, allowing variation in the columns' order:

```
output.df <- data.frame(X1=numeric(), X2=numeric(), X3=numeric(),
                        X4=numeric(), X5=numeric())

for(i in seq_along(l)) {
    if(identical(sort(colnames(l[[i]])),sort(colnames(output.df))))
        output.df[nrow(output.df)+1,] <- l[[i]][,colnames(output.df)]
}

output.df

#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  1  2  3  4  5
# 2 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: Just FYI, both of the solutions already posted ignore column order

Comment: Yes I just noticed that actually. Thx for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working too:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(l, function(x) x[!any(is.na(match(c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5"), names(x))))]))
```

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward one-liner to me! Do you see any downside to it?

Comment: @DominicComtois, no I don't see it. Yes, I'm afraid it doesn't work on all occasions. So what's the caveat?

Comment: It was an honest question, I can't see a downside neither, just wondering why you didn't pick that answer in the end.... but you say it doesn't work on all occasions?

Comment: @DominicComtois I think this could turn out to be much slower than my solution in a data frame with a large number of rows. Row slicing in R slow.

Comment: Oh, I would not accept my answer! I'm happy to see other solution, I can learn from. Thanks.

Comment: Haha true humbleness, I like that! ;) I wonder though from what size of df's we'd see a marked difference in speed, as Maximilian raised the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
na.omit(rbindlist(l, fill=TRUE)[,col, with=FALSE])
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1:  1  2  3  4  5
#2: 11 12 13 14 15
```